# JavaScript Functions and Parameters

Tags: javascript, undefined

This is a very simple JavaScript code but I get this **undefined** error, I don't know what I'm doing wrong. The result I get from the following script is **Great to see you, undefinedRaj**. Can someone please explain what does the undefined refer to and how can I remove it.

```
   var greeting = function (name) {
   document.write("Great to see you," + " " + name);
   };

   document.write(greeting(name) + "Raj");
```

Comment: Can you try greeting("Raj");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two variables called `name`. One is local to the function you create, the other is global.

The global one is never defined. So when you call `greeting(name)` you are passing `name` as `undefined`. This means that the local variable is `undefined` too.

Your intention was probably to:

1. Pass `"Raj"` as the value of `name` *and*
2. To not `document.write` the return value of the function (which, since you don't have a `return` statement in it, is also `undefined`)

Such:

```
var greeting = function (name) {
    document.write("Great to see you," + " " + name);
};

greeting("Raj");
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out Quentin.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to do this :

```
var greeting = function (name) {
    return "Great to see you," + " " + name;
};
document.write(greeting("Raj"));
```

Comment: Thanks Mohit, Quentin mentioned the RETURN element which I didn't get but your method clarified how that worked.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass `"Raj"` as a parameter to `greeting` method.

it should be

```
var greeting = function (name) {
   document.write("Great to see you," + " " + name);
};

greeting("Raj");
```

or

```
var greeting = function (name) {
   return "Great to see you," + " " + name;
};
document.write(greeting("Raj"));
```

In your code what is happening is first `greeting()` is called with global variable name which refers to `window.name` which is `''` by default so it prints `Great to see you,`, and returns `undefined` to the called, then the `document.write(greeting(name) + "Raj")` is executed here `greeting(name)` returns `undefined` as said before so it prints `undefinedRaj`, thus the result

Answer (score 1):

The function can't work because it return nothing, there is two way to do it:

```
var greeting = function (name) {
   document.write("Great to see you," + " " + name);
   };

greeting("Raj");
```

Or

```
 var greeting = function (name) {
      return ("Great to see you," + " " + name);
       };

document.write(greeting("Raj"));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want

> Great to see you, Raj

as a result,
you should call

```
greeting("Raj");
```

in the code you wrote, you are calling document.write(greeting(name))
but you did not define name before,
so you get this "undefinedRaj" message

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already used `document.write()` in the function, it is not required when you are calling the function 
Cheers http://jsfiddle.net/bQcWX/

```
var greeting = function (name) {
   document.write("Great to see you," + " " + name);
};

greeting("Raj");
```